# Seg fault while creating an array of Z3_ast from Z3_ast_vector

Tags: z3

Basically, I wanted to take an OR of many `expr`s (multiple times). I ended up creating a vector of those `expr`s and making an array from a vector and then using `Z3_mk_or`. But the code throws seg fault.

```
expr x = c.bool_const("x");
expr y = c.bool_const("y");
expr z = c.bool_const("z");    
int s=0;
int size;
Z3_ast* args;
Z3_ast_vector vec;
while(s < 2) 
{
    Z3_ast_vector_push(c, vec, x);
    Z3_ast_vector_push(c, vec, y);
    Z3_ast_vector_push(c, vec, z);
    std::cout << "size: " << Z3_ast_vector_size(c, vec) << "\n";
    size = Z3_ast_vector_size(c, vec);
    args = new Z3_ast[size];
    for(int i=0; i<size; ++i)
    {
      args[i] = Z3_ast_vector_get(c, vec, i);
    }

    expr r = to_expr(c, Z3_mk_or(c, size, args));
    s++;
    Z3_ast_vector_resize(c, vec, 0);
}
```

Also, is this the right way to approach my problem. Isn't there a simpler API call to OR many bool consts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you try instead an auxiliary function:

```
inline expr or(expr_vector const& args) { 
    array<Z3_ast> _args(args);
    Z3_ast r = Z3_mk_or(args.ctx(), _args.size(), _args.ptr());
    args.check_error();
    return expr(args.ctx(), r);
}
```

I will add this for convenience, but the use of the functions from the C API is very error prone so better to stick with the facilities provided in z3++.h

Comment: Thanks @NikolajBjorner